# Number of connected components preserved under counterimage by holomorphic embedding

Tags: general-topology

Given $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C^2$ holomorphic embedding, is it true that if $U=\bigcup_{j=1}^NU_j$ is a disjoint union of sets, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is still a disjoint union of the same number of sets?

Comment: Disjoint union yes, but same number of sets need not be the case.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: thank you very much. Doesn't the embedding property help? Are there some conditions which guarantees this property? Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

No. If $U$ is disjoint from the image of $f$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is empty which shows that the number of connected components is not preserved under preimage.